# dconcat not working on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

i am trying to display the values of a stored query i have created in an access database.
the stored query uses a number of other stored queries to calculate the results. Everything was working fine until i used the dconcat function of access in order to concatenate the values coming from some records. The strange part is that access is working correctly providing the correct results for the query while when trying to execute the new stored query on asp.net i get an "Undefined function 'DConcat' in expression" error.
i know that my query is working correctly since i get the right results every time i execute it in access but i get the problem described above when i try to get the results through an asp.net web page i have created.i would really appreciate any help on the matter since i cant find a lot of information regarding the subject online.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

User defined functions are not available outside Access. You will have to select the required records and concatenate the values in ASP.